# Are questions about bees in scope?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope, asking-questions

There is a new site proposal at Area 51: [Beekeeping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95988). We have an existing meta question [Are questions about horses and/or farm pets on topic?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36) which does not clearly include or exclude bees.  Looking at [Gardening.SE I find a couple of related questions](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=%5bpollination%5d%20bee) I think it is fair to say any pollination-type questions would be in scope there.

We do have an [insects](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insects) tag and a few questions.  In general, I feel that questions about care and housing of bees would be in scope. We allow questions about working dog tasks, so questions about harvesting honey from working bees do not seem like a stretch.

Comment: Area 51 discussion [Beekeeping may be inscope at Pets](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/23052/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm of two minds on this, I have to admit. What it boils down to me is that I'm not sure that the scope of this site should just be "pets" as we commonly come to see them. I'm really inclined to think that broadening the scope, at least beyond those that share our home, is okay.

I think Tim kind of nailed it... [We do need to start to firm up the idea of what is on topic or not](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/we-do-need-to-start-to-firm-up-the-idea-of-what-is-on-topic-or-not?lq=1)

Comment: Concur, maybe we should present a couple of answers with the arguments for and against officially broadening the scope?  Historically I have taken the more conservative stance on limiting pets, but I can form good arguments for either or both positions.

Answer (score 3):

I propose that questions involving the care of all animals (to include insects) are in scope.  Some topics are out of scope [like 'what breed is this?'](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-discourage-pet-breed-species-identification-questions)  and some questions just don't work on Stack Exchange sites. But the species of an animal does not make a question in or out of scope on Pets.SE

Questions about any **domestic** being (excluding humans) in the [Kingdom Animal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal) can be asked at Pet.SE.  Where the question is about improving the quality of life of the animal who is dependent on a human for their care, making modifications in habitat or behavior to increase the animals quality of life (or euthanasia when appropriate) and ability to coexist with the people or other animals they share living space with.

Questions about wild animals are excluded by [Are questions about semi-domesticated wild animals on topic?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-questions-about-semi-domesticated-wild-animals-on-topic)

Other discussion relating to excluding particular topics have and will continue to address those specific scenarios.

**Update Dec 2018**  There is another Beekeeping proposal on Area51, I have started [a discussion there about existing sites](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28432/you-can-ask-bee-questions-at-2-existing-stackexchange-sites)